# How to change center mode position using Carousel Anything - The Plus Addon for Elementor

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, slick.js, elementor

I'm using Carousel Anything - The Plus Addon for Elementor, using center mode with 2 columns visible, and it look like this

The image of the carousel

[image: 1]

However, I would like to switch center mode to the left column. I could not figure it out the code to do that. Can someone help me with this. Thanks very much for your support.

Comment: Note: The current center mode column is bigger and have opacity: 1; while the normal one is smaller and opacity: 0.7.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write code to do this. Enter Elementor editor and while editing, swipe the carousel right and save

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).